# Compare Dates Using JDateChooser

Tags: java, date, date-comparison

I have two boxes of `JDateChooser` and I would like to make the following comparison:

- the user will inform the first date
- when it finishes entering the second date, I make a comparison consisting of:

  - if the second date is greater than or equal to 11 days, the following message will appear:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null,
    " Homologation Date Must Be Less or Equal to 11 Days Regarding Date of Shutdown ");
```

I made a code that compares, but even when the user puts a date below the condition he is showing the message.

The following code:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
dt1 = sdf.format(dcdataDeslig.getDate().getTime());
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
dt2 = sdf1.format(dchomolog.getDate().getTime());

if (dt2.compareTo(dt1) >= 11 ) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null," Homologation Date Must Be Less or Equal to 11 Days Regarding       Date of Shutdown ");
    dchomolog.setDate(null);
    txtdataDisp.setText("");
    txtdataPg.setText("");
}
txtdataDisp.setText(dt2);
txtdataPg.setText(dt2);
```

Comment: `compareTo` return -1,0 or 1 not the difference in days

Comment: How can I compare in days, please.

Comment: Read about `java.util.Calendar`

Comment: Okay, I'll find out how you do this, Tks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `sdf.format`, the result is a `String`. It's not a date, it's a **text representing a date**.

And comparing strings won't give you the difference between 2 dates - string comparison will tell you if they are in alphabetical order, because strings represent a sequence of characters - a text - nothing more.

As far as I could understand, `dchomolog.getDate()` returns a `java.util.Date`, so the `getTime()` method will return the numerical timestamp value, which is the [number of milliseconds since Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

To calculate the difference between the dates, you can subtract the values of `getTime()`, resulting in a difference in milliseconds. Then you use a `java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit` to convert it to days:

```
// get the difference in milliseconds
long diffMillis = dchomolog.getDate().getTime() - dcdataDeslig.getDate().getTime();

// transform to days
long diffDays = TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diffMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

If the `getDate()` method returns a `java.util.Calendar` instead, just change the code to `dchomolog.getDate().getTimeInMillis()`.

### Java 8 or higher

If you have the `java.time` classes available, it's much easier - and also more reliable, as this API fixes lots of flaws from `Date` and `Calendar`.

First you can convert your dates to `Instant`'s and then use a `ChronoUnit` to calculate the difference in days:

```
long diffDays = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(dcdataDeslig.getDate().toInstant(), dchomolog.getDate().toInstant() ));
```